# Is conditional CSS possible?

Tags: css

Is it possible to give a particular styling to a child element only if say odd number of child elements are present? Let me elaborate.

I have a

```
<ul>
```

tag which gets dynamically populated with data as

```
<li>
```

child nodes. I want to apply a styling to the last element, say if only 3 child nodes are present or there are odd numbers. My present requirement is only for three child nodes. I know it is possible to do it easily with JavaScript, but I need a pure CSS solution.

Comment: yeah `:nth-child(odd)` might be what you are looking for. it will do every odd child, use `even` for every even child

Comment: if tags gets *dinamically* populated you can *dinamically* set the css classes you need for you <li>

Comment: Your question title is rather misleading, the post body is about something quite different.

Comment: Your question body could also use some clarification, it would help if the specs were a bit more precise, perhaps extended with some examples with expected output, as well as your current attempt. The use case behind your requirement might also help, because taken literally your requirement ("*style the last element if only 3 child nodes are present or there are odd numbers*") is rather strange.

Comment: i want the styling only to the last element. But it should be done only if the total number of children is odd or 3 in my case here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) and [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd)  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>x</li>
  <li>x</li>
  <li>x</li>
</ul>
```

vs

```css
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>x</li>
  <li>x</li>
  <li>x</li>
  <li>x</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Though a smart use of modern selectors, that CSS will not "*style the last element if only 3 child nodes are present or there are odd numbers*" AFAICT. E.g. try a code snippet with 5 `li`s, and it'll color the fifth one red.

Comment: @Jeroen - OP just edited his question and my answer seems to fully satisfy it. He only wants to style the last element if there are an odd number of elements. In his case, typically 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) with the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector.

To select the last element only when a specific number of elements are present, use that number for `:nth-child`:

```css
*{color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
li{
  background:#000;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  margin:2px;
  padding:0 2px;
}
li:last-child:nth-child(3){
  background:#f00;
}
hr{margin:10px 2px;}
```

```html
<ul><li></li><li></li><li>I'm red</li></ul>
<hr>
<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li>I'm not</li></ul>
```

To select the last element only when an odd number of elements are present, use `odd` for `:nth-child`:

```css
*{color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
li{
  background:#000;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  margin:2px;
  padding:0 2px;
}
li:last-child:nth-child(odd){
  background:#f00;
}
hr{margin:10px 2px;}
```

```html
<ul><li></li><li></li><li>I'm red</li></ul>
<hr>
<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li>I'm not</li></ul>
```